# use moviepy to convert legacy quicktime files

Tags: python, moviepy

I have some old quicktime files (screen caps, I think) in a weird format, that I'd like to convert via moviepy into something that plays in modern Quicktime (for example, in safari).

The old format is:

```
Codec: Apple QuickTime RLE Video (rle)
Resolution: 377x499
Buffer: 377x499
Frame Rate: 15
Decoded Format: 32 bits RGB

Stream 1:
Codec: IMA QT ADPCM Audio (ima4)
Channels: Stereo
44100 Hz, 16 Bps
```

The obvious method (`vc = VideoFileClip("in.mov"); vc.write_videofile("out.mp4", codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac")`) is not successful, and neither are various less obvious ones that I googled. The result is always a file that VLC can play (just like the original), but QuickTime can not.

I would guess the problem is the weird format (framerate, width & height), but I haven't found the incantation that would make it work.

Comment: Odd width and height can indeed cause problems in some players. Besides that, I’d recommend just using ffmpeg for this. Moviepy is overkill.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't manage to do it with `ffmpeg` either. Do you have a recommendation for how to do it with that?